# controller test_should_update: param is missing or the value is empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing

I try to test the update function in a controller class:

```
require 'test_helper'

class AppointmentsControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  include Devise::Test::IntegrationHelpers
  include Warden::Test::Helpers

  setup do
    @heikoAppointment = appointments(:appointment_heiko)
    @heiko = users(:user_heiko)
  end

 test "should update appointment" do
    login_as(@heiko)
    @heiko.confirmed_at = Time.now
    patch appointment_url(@heikoAppointment), params: { appointment: {  } }
    assert_redirected_to appointment_url(@heikoAppointment)
  end
```

however I get this error:

```
ActionController::ParameterMissing: param is missing or the value is empty: appointment
```

In fixtures I saved some data for appointment:

```
appointment_heiko:
 user: user_heiko
 appointed: <%= Time.now + 2.weeks %>
 processed: <%= Time.now - 1.weeks %>
 shopping_list: shopping_list_lebensmittel
 shopper: user_shopper
 status: <%= Appointment.statuses[:finished] %>
```

Does somebody know how I can send the params with these data from fixtures easily so that I dont get this error anymore? I am a total beginner, any code could help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting the error since the `appointment` key contains an empty hash and is not sent.

To get the attributes from a model you can use - you guessed it - [`.attributes`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods.html#method-i-attributes).

So `@heikoAppointment.attributes` would give you the attributes from the model.

But when testing an update method you should just pass the attributes you want to update and assert that they have been changed.

You should also test that any attributes that should not be modifiable are not altered.

```
before do
  login_as(@heiko)
end

test "should update appointment" do
  @heiko.confirmed_at = Time.now
  patch appointment_url(@heikoAppointment), params: { appointment: { foo: 'bar' } }
  assert_redirected_to appointment_url(@heikoAppointment)
end

test "should update appointment foo" do
  patch appointment_url(@heikoAppointment), 
        params: { appointment: { foo: 'bar' } }
  @heikoAppointment.reload # refreshes model from DB
  assert_equals( 'bar', @heikoAppointment.foo )
end 

test "should not update appointment baz" do
  patch appointment_url(@heikoAppointment), 
          params: { appointment: { baz: 'woo' } }
  @heikoAppointment.reload # refreshes model from DB
  assert_not_equal( 'woo', @heikoAppointment.foo )
end
```

Comment: As a side comment: Stick to the [naming conventions](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide) when naming your variables. Also be nice to your fellow programmers and name variables something that does not require a comment.

Comment: Thank you very much!! But how can I pass all attributes when I test the should_create_appointment? This doesnt work: post appointments_url, params: { appointment: {@heikoAppointment.attributes} }

Comment: `appointment: @heikoAppointment.attributes`. Lose the brackets as `.attributes` returns a hash.

Comment: Ok thanks!! But how about the delete function: delete appointment_url(@heikoAppointment). Here comes this error: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails

Comment: One question at a time please.